# Changing the viewController presentation style

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, I'm performing a segue from a viewController (A) and presenting a viewController (B) modally and it is working fine. I want to change the modalPresentationStyle of viewController (B) to fullscreen when a button is tapped. Please note that the button is part of viewController (B) not viewController (A).

Here is the code that I wrote in the viewController (B) to change its presentation but nothing happens.

```
@IBAction func addBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    
}
```

Could you please tell me how to change the presentationStyle to fullscreen?

Comment: on button press you take `viewController` which will be present. give it to modalPresentationStyle like suppose your contoller onject name `vc` than `vc. modalPresentationStyle = . fullScreen`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would dismiss the vc B and present it again (from vc A).

You can pass a closure to vc B (from vc A) and run that closure in the `addBtnPressed` method.

This would be the *pseudocode* for the vc A:

```swift
vcB.presentSelfAgain = { [weak self] in
    // Dismiss the current view controller (vc B).
    self?.dismiss(animated: false)
    vcB.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    // Presents the vc B again, with a different modal presentation style.
    self?.present(vcB, animated: false)
}
```

In the vc B, run this closure in the button action method:

```swift
var presentSelfAgain: (() -> Void)?

@IBAction func addBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    presentSelfAgain?()
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I would also add (to the OP and anyone else) what is the root issue - a navigation controller is a *stack* that a segue pushes/pops a view controller on, where a presented controller is much different. Sure, you may call it a "stack", but it really isn't.