# Convert modal view to fullscreen view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a modal view controller `A` presented at the top of the view controllers hierarchy.

Is it possible to make it fullscreen temporarily when a user presses a button? And then go back to standard modal look when used presses another button?

To clarify, I'm not talking about `modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` **BEFORE** `A` is presented, I need to present `A` in a standard way and then stretch it to be fullscreen when needed.

Although if I write pseudo code it would be something like this:

```
class A: UIViewController {
    @objc func goFullScreen(sender: UIButton) {
        // pseudo code:
        // modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        // go fullscreen, block `drag-to-dismiss` gesture, remove `cornerRadius`, set `self.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds`
    }   

    @objc func cancelFullScreen(sender: UIButton) {
        // pseudo code:
        // modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
        // return to the standard look of a modal view controller
    }         
}
```

I found `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate.presentationControllerShouldDismiss` method that intercepts drag to close gesture, but I don't see any way to go fullscreen.

Picture of what I am talking about:

[image]

ps. I know I can make a custom container view controller with a custom transition delegate but I'd like to know if it's possible to implement such behaviour with system classes because I basically need just to flip `modalPresentationStyle` property with some interpolation animation...

Also on the right I hide/show some UI elements, but still it's the same view controller

Comment: You would probably need to set `modalPresentationStyle` to `.custom` and use a custom presentation controller so that you can change the view frame of the presented controller as needed.

Comment: It's difficult to answer questions "in the abstract." If you provide more detail about **why** you want to do this - preferably with a couple images showing what you're trying to accomplish - it will be easier to offer suggestions.

Comment: @HangarRash yeah I'm definitely going to try that, although I hope there is some builtin method

Comment: @DonMag I've added picture with comments, could you please take a look? Basically the idea is to mimic "maximize window" button behaviour from desktop if that makes sense

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68361531/6257435 -- quick test and it works (can also "toggle" back and forth). We get a warning in Debug Console, but it appears the code satisfies the condition.

Comment: @DonMag thanks! that's smart. But this method lacks animated transition between "card" and fullscreen...

Comment: @Nik - Nope, it does not give you an "animated" transition. Because the default presentation mode also scales-down the current view, I imagine it will be pretty tough to write your own to get what you want. I have to wonder, though, if it would be worth the effort? The difference in size is so minimal... I could understand if it was something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q46yp.png

Comment: @DonMag I am totally agree it's not worth the effort (keeping in mind iPad, watch, macOS etc support too) and my goal here is to reuse system components as much as possible to keep maintenance cost low. This feature is more like nice to have UI bit :)